# How do I direct System.Diagnostics.Trace write messages to the ASP.NET trace viewer (trace.axd)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, trace

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which is deployed on an Azure instance.

In this application, I have System.Diagnostics.Trace messages all over the place, including here (quoted simply as an example):

```
public class ExceptionLogFilterAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace
            .TraceError(string.Format("{0}\r\n\r\n", 
                        filterContext.Exception.ToString()));

        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

In the web.config, I have trace enabled.

However, when I browse to trace.axd after I have been redirected to the default error page of the application because an exception has occurred, I do not see any signs of the exception I have written to the trace above.

Answer (score 0):

Add this configuration in your web.config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <trace>
      <listeners>
         <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, 
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, 
            Version=1.0.0.0, 
            Culture=neutral, 
            PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            name="AzureDiagnostics">
            <filter type="" />
         </add>
      </listeners>
   </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Here is where you can [read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714589.aspx) about it.